# How to delete lines matching a pattern from a file using Tcl/Expect

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am trying to understand how to work with expect.

I want to check if a file has a certain string in it and if it does contain it than delete the whole line, i know how i would do that with bash with if and grep, but im fairly new to expect and i am having issues with getting it to work the basic idea is this ( in bash script )

```
if grep -q "string" "file";
then
    echo "something is getting deleted".
    sed -i "something"/d "file"
    echo Starting SCP protocol
else
    echo "something was not found"
    echo Starting SCP protocol. 
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expect is generally used to "chat"  with interactive programs. It's the output of programs that the branches will depend on rather than the contents of a file. Are you sure you're using the right tool? For your specific situation, bash seems sufficient.

Comment: In this case you are correct but the next part of the script requires me to scp a file and then ssh to a system and i want to do that automatically and expect does the work nicely, but i need to check for the string so i would know how to organize my expect commands

Comment: What you posted look like bash rather than expect

Comment: That is bash, What i am asking is can i do the same with the script above with expect.

Comment: @Mike.G ssh and scp can be set up to work without prompts. This will be preferable to trying to automating it using expect. Consider that before doing this. If you still want to go the expect route, use either [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/367) or [this](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) to check the contents of the file. Expect is a TCL extension so that's the syntax you should be using.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `man sshpass`.

Comment: you can also try [passh](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach: using Tcl as a glue language, like the shell, calling out to system tools:

```
if {[catch {exec grep -q "string" "file"} output] == 0} {
    puts "something is getting deleted".
    exec sed -i "something"/d "file"
} else {
    puts "something was not found"
}
puts "Starting SCP protocol"
```

See https://wiki.tcl.tk/1039#pagetoce3a5e27b for a thorough explanation of using `catch` and `exec`

More current Tcl would look like

```
try {
    exec grep -q "string" "file"
    puts "something is getting deleted".
    exec sed -i "something"/d "file"
} on error {} {
    puts "something was not found"
}
puts "Starting SCP protocol"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since @whjm deleted his answer, here's a pure-Tcl way to accomplish your task:

```
set filename "file"
set found false
set fh [open $filename r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {string} $line]} {
        puts "something is getting deleted"
        close $fh

        set fh_in [open $filename r]
        set fh_out [file tempfile tmpname]
        while {[gets $fh_in line] != -1} {
            if {![regexp {something} $line]} {
                puts $fh_out $line
            }
        }
        close $fh_in
        close $fh_out
        file rename -force $tmpname $filename

        set found true
        break        
    }
}
if {!$found} {close $fh}
puts "Starting SCP protocol"
```